# VS2013 Breakpoint will not be hit... source code is different from the version built

Tags: visual-studio

[NOTE: I do not believe this is a duplicate though it is similar to other listed questions.]

After much searching and finding no solution to this error, I have gone forward with unchecking the option “Require source files to exactly match the original version".  But would prefer to actually fix the problem and not hide it.

1. Confirmed that "Define DEBUG constant" and "Define TRACE constant" are checked in project properties; also confirmed "Debug Info" is set to "Full" under "Advanced".
2. Used chkmatch to confirm the DLL/PDB signatures match.
3. Deleted the bin & obj folders, did "Clean Solution" in VS, rebooted computer, ran VS and did a "Build".  Still comes up with the error.
4. Checked modules list (Debug > Window > Modules) and found that it was using PDBs located in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\*value*\*value*\assembly\dl3\*value*\*value*.  I deleted all of these and tried step #2 again.  Still came up with the error.  Using chkmatch, I confirmed the those that got copied into these folders are the same as those in the bin folder.

Simply cannot figure out what is causing this.  It all worked fine last week.  The only change I can think of is that I edited the "Release" configuration to remove the tests from the build.

Comment: Do you have multiple projects in the solution?  Your references are probably not Project references, but have been added by browsing to the /bin folder (NO! BAD DEVELOPER!).  Remove references to them from your web project, re-add PROJECT references.  Do not browse to a bin folder to add a reference.

Comment: There are multiple projects in the solution but they were all added by creating the projects in VS.  It would be stupid for someone to add a project by browsing to the /bin folder.

Comment: People are stupid all the time.